# Free bluetooth software for file transfer

Tags: software-rec, bluetooth

I used to use bluesoleil to transfer files between my mobile phone(Nokia) and my pc. But now bluesoleil is not free anymore. I tried to use the bluetooth software come default with my lenovo laptop, but the transfer always stop after some time. Do you have any free bluetooth software for replacement?

I am using xp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bluetooth transfer shouldn't timeout. Couple of things to try:

- See if your [Lenovo bluetooth driver](http://getpcdrivers.com/uk/Download.php) needs to be updated
- Grab the [Bluetooth File Transfer OBEX](http://www.brothersoft.com/bluetooth-file-transfer-obex-ftp-j2me-157131.html)

Also check the software on your Nokia is up to date.